Correlation matrix heatmap
I performed a correlation matrix for four field campaigns using the code below.
However, I got the following error:
NameError
                               
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_19684\903953116.py in <module>

      8 corr_Field1 = df_corr_Field1.corr()
     10 sns.heatmap(corr_Field1, annot=True, cmap='coolwarm', ax=axes[0], center=0,mask=mask)
     11 axes[0].set_title('Field1')

NameError: name 'mask' is not defined

How can I sort this out?
# Set up the matplotlib figure
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(20, 6))

df_corr = dt[['Label','CE(µS/cm)', 'pH','HCO3-','Cl-', 'SO4', 'NO3-', 'Na+', 'K+', 'Ca2+', 'Mg2+', 'NH4+', 'TC', 'IC', 'COT']]

# Generate subdata for 'Fiedl1'
df_corr_Field1 = df_corr[df_corr['Label'] == 'Fiedl1']
corr_Field1 = df_corr_Field1.corr()

sns.heatmap(corr_Field1, annot=True, cmap='coolwarm', ax=axes[0], center=0,mask=mask)
axes[0].set_title('Field1')

# Generate subdata for 'Field2'
df_corr_Field2 = df_corr[df_corr['Label'] == "Field2"]
corr_Field2 = df_corr_Fiedl2.corr()

sns.heatmap(corr_Field2, annot=True, cmap='coolwarm', ax=axes[1], center=0,mask=mask)
axes[1].set_title("Field2")

# Generate subdata for 'Field3'
df_corr_Field3 = df_corr[df_corr['Label'] == 'Field3']
corr_Field3 = df_corr_Field3.corr()

sns.heatmap(corr_Field3, annot=True, cmap='coolwarm', ax=axes[2], center=0,mask=mask)
axes[2].set_title('Field3')

# Generate subdata for 'Field4'
df_corr_Field4 = df_corr[df_corr['Label'] == 'Field4']
corr_Field4 = df_corr_Field.corr()

sns.heatmap(corr_Field4, annot=True, cmap='coolwarm', ax=axes[2], center=0, mask=mask)
axes[2].set_title('Field4')

# Display the subplots
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


The error refers to the argument mask=mask that repeasts several time the code, e.g.:
sns.heatmap(corr_Field1, annot=True, cmap='coolwarm', ax=axes[0], center=0, mask=mask)
# Here ---------------------------------------------------------------------^

The "mask" on the left is the name of the keyword argument of the heatmap function. The "mask" on the right is the value you want to assign to it. Since you don't actually have a variable called "mask", this errors out, as you've seen. 
Since it doesn't seem your code sets up anything that should actually be passed there, you can just omit it:
sns.heatmap(corr_Field1, annot=True, cmap='coolwarm', ax=axes[0], center=0)

